# ActionListener does not work to move data from on JList to the Other JList by the button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jlist, defaultlistmodel

My program is based on a API. I got a JList with and a model that has a some names. And a selectListener to get the seleted item and a button to send that item to the other window which has another Here is my first list:

First List (window) and send the items to the other list.

```
final DefaultListModel<String> Names = new DefaultListModel<String>();
final JList<MyAPI> Places = new JList(Names);

private JList<MyAPI> locList;
private DefaultListModel<MyAPI> favourites;

    public AddLocation(JList<MyAPI> locList, DefaultListModel<MyAPI> favourites){
        this.locList = locList;
        this.favourites = favourites;
}


addThis.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     Object chose = Places.getSelectedValue();
     favourites.addElement((MyAPI) chose); // error in this line
                }
            });
```

And this is the other window that selected items should be added to here:

```
final DefaultListModel<MyAPI> favourites;
final JList<MyAPI> locList;

favourites = new DefaultListModel<MyAPI>();
locList = new JList<MyAPI>(favourites);
```

So now both windows loads and the first list loads with its names in it. but when I press the button add this, it gives error and points to this line:

```
favourites.addElement((MyAPI) chose);
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your first model is defined like this:

```
final DefaultListModel<String> Names ...;
```

Your second model is defined like this:

```
final DefaultListModel<MyAPI> favourites;
```

Your first list model conains `String` instances, your second model contains `MyAPI` instances. So when this line is executed:

```
favourites.addElement((MyAPI) chose);
```

you are trying to make a `MyAPI` out of a `String`, which does not work and probably a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Either you need to declare the second list model as `final DefaultListModel<String> favourites;` or you create an instance of `MyAPI` based on the selected `String` (`new MyAPI(chose)` ?).